# Why can't I use the function symbol(#') extracted from the list in Common lisp?

Tags: function, functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp

The first one doesn't work.
But the second one works,which make me confused..
Could anyone explain a bit about that?

```
CL-USER> (funcall (first '(#'+ +)) 1)
; Evaluation aborted on #<TYPE-ERROR expected-type:
;  (OR FUNCTION SYMBOL) datum: #'+>.
CL-USER> (funcall #'+ 1)
1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`#'`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhb.htm) is a reader macro. `#'+` is an abbreviation for `(function +)`. `'` is a reader macro expanding to `(quote …)`. The latter returns its argument unevaluated. So, `'(#'+ +)` yields `((function +) +)` (`#'+` will be turned into `(function +)` at read-time). The `first` of this is just the list `(function +)`, which is not a function. Now, `(function +)` is printed as `#'+`, which is what you see in the debugger.

Using non-literal lists will work:

```
CL-USER> (funcall (first (list #'+ '+)) 1)
1
```

Comment: Thanks danlei. As you say,the result of `(first '(#'+ +))` is `(function +)`, right? But why wasn't  it evaluated into `#'+` automatically? what's the different with `#'+` and `(function +)`? Aren't they both **function objects**?

Comment: The question is rather: Why wasn't it evaluated to a function? (Remember `#'` is just a reader macro, nothing gets "evaluated into #'+"). `'(#'+ +)` will be read as `(quote ((function +) +)`, that happens at read time, i.e. the expansion of reader macors. Now, since the `(function +)` is inside of a quoted expression, it will just be returned unevaluated, since that's what `quote` does.

Comment: After read-time, there is no difference between `#'+` and `(function +)`. `#'+` is just an abbreviation which expands to `(function +)`, but that's just a list – *code*, but still a list. So, `(function +)` is not a function object, but will yield a function object *when evaluated*. `quote` *does not* evaluate its argument, which is why `(function +)` stays what it is: A list (which happens to be code which, when evaluated, returns a function object).

Comment: I see. Thanks! (I tried `(first '((+ 3 4 ) + 2 3))` and it returned `(+ 3 4)` instead of `7`, then I understand~)

Answer (score 5):

Your input is:

```
 (funcall (first '(#'+ +)) 1)
```

What is `'(#'+ +)` when we evaluate it? The quote in front prevents the evaluation of the form, so the result is just what the reader has read as data:

It is a list with two items:

1. `(function +)`
2. `+`

Typically written as ((function +) +).

Note that the quote in your original input explicitly said that you did not want to evaluate the list or its contents.

Now you call `FIRST` on this list. The result is the first item: `(function +)`. This is a list of two items:

1. `function`
2. `+`

Now you call FUNCALL with this list and the value 1.

FUNCALL expects a function or a symbol as the input. You give it the list `(function +)` as the first argument. FUNCALL does not know what to do with it.

How can we repair it? You probably wanted to use the function which is the result of evaluating `(function +)`.

So you need to rewrite your original list. Instead of `'(#'+ +))' use for example:

```
(list #'+ '+)
```

or

```
`(,#'+ +)    ; note the backquote in front
```